# If I buy Call of Duty: World at War, does it come with custom Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

I got $20 for Easter and I was wondering if *Call of Duty: World at War* automatically came with custom zombies, or do I have to buy the custom Zombies?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom" zombies?

Comment: likes maps that other people make and you can download them and put it into the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not get any custom zombie maps no, however you CAN download them and put them into your game. If I recall correctly as well there are 2 zombie skins that were available in the game itself if you had a certain purchase.

However if you want the entire zombie experience*and you have the money) you will have to buy the Zombie package which costs about 170$ it includes all the zombie stuff from all the CoD games that had zombie modes black ops, World at war etc...

If you want to get the custom zombie maps here https://steamcommunity.com/groups/Imlikingmyzombies

This should give you a head start. Hope that helps :)

Comment: But if I just buy the game on steam for 20$ can I still play custom zombies?

Comment: You have access to the zombie mode yes... However you're starting to confuse me with your "custom zombies" according to the response you gave the comment on your question, by "custom zombies" you most likey mean custom zombie maps. And like I said in my post you don't get them included no. Some may be downloadable in game however I can't confirm that as the game is quite old now. However you can downloaded outside sources and get those custom maps if you want more. (Link posted in my answer?)